# Surface tension versus stress in a balloon's membrane

Tags: stress-strain, surface-tension

I am conducting an experiment in which I am measuring how the internal pressure in a balloon varies with its circumference. To explain the relationship (shown in the graph below) I decided to calculate stress & strain values of the balloon's membrane.[image: Pressure vs radius]

I know that the internal pressure balances the surface tension of the balloon's membrane and the atmospheric pressure (picture below), therefore internal pressure does depend on the surface tension.
[image: force diagram]

At first I thought for a balloon the surface tension and the stress of it membrane are the same thing but when searching for equations to calculate surface tension/stress specifically for balloons, I found 2 different equations from the same source(LNCS 0637 - Rubber and Rubber Balloons (Frontmatter Pages)) :

For surface tension,

[image]

For stress,

[image]

So then I tried searching for the difference between surface tension and stress for a balloon but to no avail.

Thee equations seem to suggest they are different but are they really? And what is the difference?

Comment: See. the following link:  https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/pressurized-containers-stress-distribution-and-large-displacements.1055264/#post-6929013

Comment: @ChetMiller do you have a simple answer because I cannot understand the mathematics in the source sent by you.

Comment: It's just algebra.

Answer (score 0):

Please give a link to available resources that you refer to. I assume the content you're using is [here](https://d-nb.info/972144528/34), Müller and Strehlow, *Rubber and Rubber Balloons: Paradigms of Thermodynamics* (2004).

Surface tension and stress aren't the same thing; they don't even take the same units. Surface tension is the (in this context, effective) energy penalty of increasing a surface area. Stress is a force applied applied over a cross-sectional area (in this context, a cross section through the rubber skin of the balloon). Note the different numerators: energy and force. Note the different areas: surface and cross-sectional.